# How can I properly implement commerce data relationships in a sql database?

Tags: sql, database-design

First, I'd like to start out expressing that I am not trying to just have someone create my table schema for me. I have spent some time weighing the options between the two possibilities in my design and I wanted to get some advice before I go and run wild with my current idea.

Here is my current schema, I will put a ? next to columns I'm considering using.

Key:

```
table_name
----------
col1 | col2 | col3

tax_zone
---------
tax_zone_id | tax_rate | description

sales_order
-----------
sales_order_id | tax_zone_id (FK) or tax_rate (?)

sales_order_item
-----------
sales_order_item_id | sales_order_id (FK) | selling_price | amount_tax or tax_rate (?)
```

So, if it wasn't already clear, the dilemma is whether or not I should store the tax data in the individual rows for an order, or use a join to pull the tax_zone information and then do something in my query like `(tz.tax_rate * so.order_amount) as order_total`.

At present, I was thinking of using the method I just described. There is a problem I see with this methodology though that I can't seem to figure out how to remedy. Tax rates for specific zones are subject to change. This means that if a tax rate changes for a zone and I'm using a foreign key reference, the change in the rate will reflect in past orders that were done with a different rate. This causes an issue because at present I'm using the data in this table to store both orders that have been processed and orders that are still open, therefore if someone were to go re-print a past order, the total amount for the order will have changed.

My problem with storing the specific rate or tax amount is that it means every time someone was going to edit an order, I would have to update that row again with the changes to those values.

In the process of writing this, I'm starting to move towards the latter idea being the better of the two.

Perhaps if someone can just provide me the answer to the following questions so I can go research them myself some more.

Is this a known problem in database modeling?
Are there any well known "authorities" on the subject that have published a book / article?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: One minor nitpick: here in Europe VAT-rate depends on the item being sold (currently, there are two: VAT-low=4% and VAT-high=18% IIRC). So the column for the "tax category/zone being used" should be moved from the sales_order to the sales_order_item table.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I wasn't aware of the VAT setup in Europe. Our company deals almost exclusively with US clients, I'll definitely modify it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, versioning and history is a well known problem in database modelling. Your solution is very common.

For a simple enumeration like VAT-rates a simple "foreign key tax_id referencing taxtable(id)" will do. The tax-table should never be updated, once a tax_id is enterered, it should stay there forever. If the tax rates are changed at the end of the year, new record should be entered into the tax_table **even if records with the new value already exist**.

The best search phrase for search engines is probably "temporal database".

UPDATE:
http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.faapartners.com%2Fdownloads%2Foverige-publicaties%2Fpresentatie-over-tijd-in-databases%2Fat_download%2Ffile&rct=j&q=veldwijk%20temporal&ei=HQdxTtimCcKr-QansM28CQ&usg=AFQjCNEg9puU8WR1KIm90voSDp13WmE0-g&cad=rja

Answer (score 1):

2 points. You're going to have to store the tax rate somewhere or you're not going to be able to add it to sales_order, or anywhere else. Secondly the tax rate can change over time so you don't want to update each time.

So you have two options.

Store tax rate in a reference table and update each order with the correct tax rate at the time of entry into the table.

Calculate everything every time you access it.

**Personally** I would go for option 1 BUT have a start time as part of the Primary Key in the reference table as if you ever do need to change the tax-rate you may need to know what the correct rate was at the time the order was placed.

Answer (score 1):

In the situation you describe, you will eventually have to store the tax rate in the orders table, because you will need the rate at which the order was closed.

Therefore the cleanest solution has to be to calculate the tax rate each time an order is updated unless it is closed.  You could use a trigger to do this.

(Ben's answer popped up as I was writing this - seems we disagree, which is probably not helpful :-)

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Taxes DO change and yet you need to remember what rate was charged at the time the order was submitted. Ditto anythign that can change - product prices, shipping, etc. etc. Reference rates for new orders but copy/snapshot them to each order when submitted. Yes, you will have to continutally update the order each time it is edited but 'freeze' those values when submitted.

Comment: @chrispanda we don't disagree! I would add the rate at the time of the order but just store the rate in a different table. How else are you going to add it to the orders table?

Comment: What do you think about @wildplasser 's idea?

I am considering something to this effect based on his submission. I will have a table that stores a tax_zone_id | tax_rate | datetime_entered.

My query for pulling the tax_rate information would then look something like this.

`SELECT tr.tax_rate, so.sales_order_id FROM sales_order so JOIN tax_zone tz ON so.tax_zone_id = tz.tax_zone_id` , then you'll have to forgive my lack of immediate sql knowledge, but the remainder of the query would be something to the effect of the tax_rate where the dateentered < orderdate LIMIT 1

Comment: I believe you should always try and do the simplest thing that could possibly work and so I think in this case @wildplasser's approach is unnecessarily complex.  I see no value in having the tax stored in the order's table as a key onto the tax_zone table, because this does not give any benefits as far as I can see, and has a cost in that it requires a join when retrieving the order. Why not just put the tax payable in the order table when the order is created/updated?  That said I do not claim to be an expert on this, and someone may well come up with a reason why this is not a good solution